# ReST separator without rendering a space

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

This has come up in a few places, but I'll use footnotes as an example. Let's say I have some ReST text that references a footnote:

```
can be rendered in a single batch [#foot-diffuse]_.
```

This looks like this when rendered:

[image: ugly space]

There shouldn't be a space after text when referencing a footnote. This is what I want it to look like:

[image: correct rendering]

The problem is that the space between `batch` and `[#foot-diffuse]_` is not optional. Taking it out makes the ReST not valid and the footnote doesn't get rendered at all. Is there some way to insert a separator between a word and a directive in ReST without it getting rendered as a space in the final output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out you can escape the space. This works:

```
can be rendered in a single batch\ [#foot-diffuse]_.
```